# Terminology: Is DTW considered to be machine learning or signal processing?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, signal-processing

The [DTW Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) puts this method in the category "Machine learning algorithms". On the other hand, the famous paper "[Dynamic Programming Algorithm Optimization for
Spoken Word Recognition](https://www.irit.fr/~Julien.Pinquier/Docs/TP_MABS/res/dtw-sakoe-chiba78.pdf)" was published in IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing, indicating that DTW might have been considered a signal processing algorithm by the authors.

Admittedly, the term machine learning might not have been as common in 1978 as it is today but I still wonder the following: Is DTW considered to be a machine learning algorithm or a signal processing algorithm?

Comment: Some teach PCA as a ML tool

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I was asking about DTW, not PCA.

Comment: You can anything a machine learning algorithm

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an accepted answer to this question. (Which would be ironic if you were to accept an answer in this thread.) Signal processers and machine learners will both use DTW in their work and consider it "theirs".

There are [170 hits on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=DTW) and [83 results on SignalProcessing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=DTW), but of course the two sites have very different traffic, and DTW is probably more important to signal processing "as a whole" than to statistics "as a whole".